# What is sympy version of math.modf in python's built-in module?

Tags: python, sympy

When we have a floating number like `123.82423992`, with `math.modf` like this:

```
>>> math.modf(123.82423992)
>>> (0.8242399199999966, 123.0)
```

I need to do that operation with `sympy`, is there any `sympy` version of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number `n` is positive, you can use `Mod(n, 1)` and `floor(n)`.

For negative numbers, because of the way mod and floor in SymPy (which uses Python conventions) handle negative arguments, you'll need to use `1 - Mod(n, 1)` and `floor(n) + 1`.

You can combine these into single expressions with `Piecewise`.

```
Piecewise((Mod(n, 1), n >= 0), (1 - Mod(n, 1), n < 0))
Piecewise((floor(n), n >= 0), (1 + floor(n), n < 0))
```

**EDIT: You can also use `frac(n)` instead of `Mod(n, 1)`. I can't comment on which is better.**